Automatically declare parameters from yaml in composable node
I am using hybrid planning for my project, and I have a list of parameters to set, so I don't want to declare them one by one.
I try to use launch file to load the yaml into the composable node, setting extra_arguments doesn't seem to set the automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides and allow_undeclared_parameters
    container = ComposableNodeContainer(
        name="hybrid_planning_container",
        namespace="/lbr",
        package="rclcpp_components",
        executable="component_container_mt",
        composable_node_descriptions=[
            // other ComposableNode
            ComposableNode(
                package="paradocs_planning",
                plugin="moveit::hybrid_planning::HybridPlanningManager",
                name="hybrid_planning_manager",
                parameters=[
                    common_hybrid_planning_param,
                    PathJoinSubstitution(
                        [
                            FindPackageShare("paradocs_planning"),
                            "config",
                            "hybrid_planning_manager.yaml",
                        ]
                    ),
                    robot_description,
                ],
                extra_arguments=[
                    {"use_intra_process_comms": True},
                    {'automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides': True},
                    {'allow_undeclared_parameters': True}
                ],
            ),
        ],
        output="screen",
    )

paradocs_planning/config/hybrid_planning_manager.yaml, some nested parameters
/**:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_logic_plugin_name: "moveit_hybrid_planning/MotionCompensation"
    robot_description: "robot_description"
    planning_group: "arm"

    robot_description_kinematics:
      arm:
        kinematics_solver: pick_ik/PickIkPlugin
        kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.05
        kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
        mode: global
        position_scale: 1.0
        rotation_scale: 0.5
        position_threshold: 0.001
        orientation_threshold: 0.01
        cost_threshold: 0.001
        minimal_displacement_weight: 0.0
        gd_step_size: 0.0001

In my hybrid_planning_manager.cpp, I tried also declared .automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true) and       .allow_undeclared_parameters(true) in the hybrid_planning_manager.h but didn't work either.
namespace
{
const rclcpp::Logger LOGGER = rclcpp::get_logger("hybrid_planning_manager");
}  // namespace

namespace moveit::hybrid_planning
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  HybridPlanningManager::HybridPlanningManager(const rclcpp::NodeOptions& options = rclcpp::NodeOptions()
      .automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides(true)
      .allow_undeclared_parameters(true))
    : Node("hybrid_planning_manager", options), initialized_(false), stop_hybrid_planning_(false)
  {
    // Initialize hybrid planning component after construction
    RCLCPP_WARN(LOGGER, "auto declare %d", Node::get_node_options().automatically_declare_parameters_from_overrides());
 
    // The rest of the constructor
  }

The output from RCLCPP_WARN(LOGGER, "auto declare %d"
$ auto declare 0

I did some research, but these are not quite relevant because I believe they all declared the parameters in the code, which I don't want to do.
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/715
https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/issues/156
Original hybrid-planning repo
https://github.com/moveit/moveit2/tree/main/moveit_ros/hybrid_planning
